# What does it mean for a dictionary to be full? (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

So I'm working on a program that involves the Map interface, specifically TreeMap. Our directions say something about detecting if the "dictionary is full". I'm not super familiar with dictionaries, so what exactly does it mean for a dictionary to be full?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @BryanOakley oops, Java.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get more specific directions about what that means. Other than running out of memory which isn't a condition that you typically handle in program logic, there's no real notion of a Map being full in Java.

Comment: Given that TreeMap returns its size as an int I would assume it can be no larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE. Not that I would see anyone putting over 2 billion objects into a tree map.